# How do I do the wall jump in Super Metroid?

Tags: super-metroid

I have always had a problem with the wall jump in *Super Metroid*. Is there some trick to getting it to work?

As a kid, when I got to the pit in Brinstar where the etecoons try to teach you to wall jump, the only way for me to get out was to roll into a ball and use my turbo controller to bomb jump myself out. I could never figure out how to properly do the wall jump.

Comment: I was the same way, I could *never* get this as a kid... or even as a teen/into my twenties. Interestingly enough, playing on the ii U's virtual console I now find I'm able to do the wall jump and was able to get to the top with the etecoons. I don't know if that's because the controller is better, the emulation makes the process slightly easier, or I just never had the skills before...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a trick to the timing, that I only just discovered (after having played this game for years).

When jumping towards the wall, you do not push away and jump at the same time (which would make sense). Instead, you have to push away from the wall, and *then* push jump, about 150-250 ms later.

The trick is to watch for Samus's sprite to change from somersaulting to this:

[image: Samus ready to do a wall jump]

The instant you see that sprite, push the jump button.

Comment: That's a trick that takes a bit of timing to get right.  Once you do, though, it's smooth sailing.

Comment: "which would make sense". That really depends. So many games do it different ways, because they think it makes sense their way. Personally, I think it makes sense if you push the direction away from the wall *after* you push jump. To each their own.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it'll help to look at it from this angle:  **"What is one of the most common pitfalls that causes you to screw up walljumping?"**  In my experience, once you accidentally hit up or down on the D-pad, you lose the ability to walljump. So be careful to ONLY push left and right.

Once I adopted this habit, I found I rarely ever screw it up anymore.